# How can I select a sqlite column with multiple lines in bash?

Tags: bash, sqlite

I have a sqlite database table with three columns that is storing Name, Location, and Notes. It appears that everything is stored correctly, as when using the sqlite command line I see the correct number of columns and the data is grouped correctly.

The problem comes when using a bash script (this is a requirement) to access the data. The "Notes" column stores data that can potentially be multiple lines (with newlines and such). When I query this table, using something like the following:

```
stmt="Select name, location, notes from t1"  
sqlite3 db "$stmt" | while read ROW;   
do  
  name=`echo $V_ROW | awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[1]}'`  
  location=`echo $V_ROW | awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[2]}'`  
  notes=`echo $V_ROW | awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[3]}'`  
done
```

I end up with everything normal until the first newline character in the notes column.  After this, each note line is treated as a new row. What would be the correct way to handle this in bash?

Comment: You should take a look at the [`.mode`](https://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) command to `sqlite3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data is pipe separated, you can do this (untested): read each line into an array; check the size of the array

- if 3 fields, then you have a row from the db, but the notes field may be incomplete. Do something with the *previous* row, which by now has a complete notes field.
- if 1 field found, append the field value to the current notes field.

```
  sqlite3 db "$stmt" | {
    full_row=()
    while IFS='|' read -ra row; do  
      if [[ ${#row[@]} -eq 3 ]]; then
        # this line contains all 3 fields
        if [[ ${#full_row[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
           : # "row" is the first row to be seen, nothing to do here
        else
           name=${full_row[0]}
           location=${full_row[1]}
           notes=${full_row[2]}
           do_something_with "$name" "$location" "$notes"
           #
           # not necessary to use separate vars
           # do_something_with "${row[@]}"
        fi
        # then store the current row with incomplete notes
        full_row=( "${row[@]}" )     
      else
        # only have notes.
        full_row[2]+=" "${row[0]}
      fi
    done
  }
```

You better takes steps to ensure the notes field does not contain your field separator (`|`)